# Throw a NotImplementedError in PHP?

Tags: php, exception

Is there a kind of NotImplementedError in PHP?

I want to add these to some stub-methods and interfaces, so as to warn classes that extend me, they still have work to do. Or is this achieved differently in PHP?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

PHP does not have a built-in `NotImplementedException` however you're welcome to create your own. I suppose [`BadMethodCallException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.badmethodcallexception.php) comes close which would be a decent candidate for extension

```
class NotImplementedException extends BadMethodCallException
{}
```

... and in your method

```
public function notImplementedMethod()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

You can also very simply do something like this

```
throw new Exception('Not implemented');
```

Comment: Just an improvement to the good answer: use `\BadMethodCallException` and `\Exception` (with _backslash_) if you are using namespaces (PHP >= 5.3.0).

Comment: A suggestion: `NotImplementedException` should extend [`\RuntimeException`](https://php.net/manual/en/class.runtimeexception.php)

Comment: @caligari Can you explain why?

Comment: @JohnM. because this is NOT "bad method call" since it's called properly, but is not implemented and does not do what it supposed to. It's much closer to `RuntimeException` because it's something which should not happen during runtime.

Comment: @Wirone A `RuntimeException` is an error "which can only be found on runtime." To me, it's closer to a `BadMethodCall` because the author should know not to call the method -- it's determinable prior to runtime.

Comment: @JohnM. ok, maybe you're right. I was enclosed within `BadMethodCallException`'s description and didn't think in a way that `NotImplementedExceptions` extends that description (usage), not the class only.

Comment: If the author should know not to call this method throwing or extending `LogicException` would be the most logical.

Comment: extending `LogicException` sounds better for me too

Comment: This debate is pointless. Implementations can extend whatever they like or just throw a plain `Exception`. It's completely opinion based at this point

Comment: The debate is not pointless anymore. Current IDEs like PhpStorm suggest to catch or annotate exceptions based on \RuntimeException, but not based on \LogicException. This sould not be catched and should break the execution instead.

Comment: Regarding `BadMethodCallException` vs `LogicException`: BadMethodCallException extends BadFunctionCallException, which extends LogicException. So they are both correct ;)

Comment: @caligari please dont; use `use BadMethodCallException` at the top of the file instead; this significantly improves readability