# How to throw a Not Implemented Error

Tags: php, error-handling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Throw a NotImplementedError in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092886/throw-a-notimplementederror-in-php)

When writing base-classes, I often develop gradually, and only build what I need (Or, what I am testing). Yet I like my interface to be balanced. For every getter a setter. When implmenting CRUD, even when right now, I need only the R, I'd rather write the stubs for CUD laready.

I want these to throw some Not Implemented Exception. How can I raise such errors or exceptions?

For example:

```
class Resource {
  /**
   * get Issues a GET-request to Online, fetch with $this::$id
   * @returns $this
   */
  protected function get() {
    if ($this->id) {
      $attributes = http_build_query(array("id" => $this->id));
      $url = "{$this->url}?{$attributes}";
      $options = array_merge(array('method' => 'GET'));
      $response = _http_request($url, $options);
      $this->parse($response);
    }
    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * post Place a new object on Online
   *
   * @param $attributes ....
   * @returns Source $this
   */
  protected function post($attributes = array()) {
    throw new NotImplementedError();
  }

  /**
   * put Updates an object on Online
   *
   * @param $attributes ....
   * @returns $this
   */
  protected function put($attributes = array()) {
    throw new NotImplementedError();
  }

  /**
   * delete Removes an object from Online, selected by $this::$id.
   * @returns $this
   */
  protected function delete() {
    throw new NotImplementedError();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes. It is a duplicate. Problem is that searching for "not implemented error PHP" gives hundreds of pages with questions about some lib or class throwing that error. I.e: I searched, but did not find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this previous answer: [Throw a NotImplementedError in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092886/throw-a-notimplementederror-in-php)

Very simply put, one doesn't exist in PHP, but you can easily create your own by extending an existing Exception. The previous answer suggests using BadMethodCallException to do this:

```
class NotImplementedException extends BadMethodCallException
{}
```

Then you can throw a NotImplementedException within your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can `throw new NotImplementedException()` - just like [this one](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Locale/Exception/NotImplementedException.html) from the Symfony API.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it you have 2 possibilities:

1. Derive from the exception class and implement a `not implemented exception`, that you can throw.
2. Define the not implemented methods as abstract. The compiler will then generate a error. Do not forget to mark the entire base class as abstract.